# Splitting integer interval into disjoint sequences, union of which contains every number in the interval

Tags: sequences-and-series, interval-arithmetic

I am a math noobie, so this might have an obvious solution, but I'd be curious if there is a simple (or a complicated) way to split an integer interval of arbitrary size into exactly `n`, disjoint sequences so that a set union of all the sequences contains every number in the interval.

I figured one way would include numbers where the lowest common denominator would be larger than (or at least as large as) the largest number in the interval but I have gotten a bit lost on a way as my theoretical framework isn't quite solid enough.

Also, I am very sorry if the textual representation of the requirements is a bit vague, but despite my best effors, task of translating that into some kind of notation was drastically beyond my capabilities.

Comment: A sequence has a countable number of elements, so does a finite union of sequences. An interval on the other hand has an uncountable number of elements.

Comment: Sorry, meant integer interval. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Still unclear to me. You can cover an integer interval $[a, b]$ with a single sequence $a, a+1, a+2, \ldots, b$.

Comment: Yep, realized that just before you commented, hence the edited question, I actually want exactly _n_. If it would help, my use-case comes from distributed computing, I want distributedly number elements of a list in a way that no two machines can assign a same number to an element of a list

Comment: So where is the problem? Choose $a, a+n, a+2n, \ldots$ as the first sequence, $a+1, a+n+1, a+2n+1, \ldots$ as the second sequence, and so on.

Comment: Oh, okay, I assumed I was missing some entirely trivial solution. Thanks